Getting this error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:" while trying to run the below script in Selenium Java
public class BrokenlinksTest {
public static  void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "\"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe\"");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");        
        List<WebElement> Listlinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("size of links and images" +Listlinks.size());
        List<WebElement> activelinks = new ArrayList<WebElement>(); 
        for (int i=0; i<Listlinks.size(); i++) {
            if(Listlinks.get(i).getAttribute("href")!= null) {
                activelinks.add( Listlinks.get(i));         }
            System.out.println("size of active links and images" + activelinks.size()); }
        for (int j=0; j<activelinks.size(); j++) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            String response = connection.getResponseMessage();
            connection.disconnect();
            System.out.println(j +"."+ activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")+ response ); }}}
            


This looks like Java. Please add the "Java" tag to your question so that it's clear. You also need to edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Maybe you were missing some imports or got the wrong imports? I'm not sure the below code works fine for me.
I made a couple changes...

As of Selenium 4.6, SeleniumManager was added and it automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the appropriate driver for you. So, you no longer need to use a DriverManager or specify the path, etc.

In the first loop, you are making sure that href is not null. There's a faster way to do this. Just add a check to the locator to ensure that an href exists using a CSS selector. This
driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

becomes
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href]"));


You probably want to update your Selenium version to the newest. Your .pageLoadTimeout() and .implicitlyWait() calls are using an old syntax.

I updated the logging text to be more readable... at least to me. Feel free to change it to whatever you want.


The updated code
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BrokenlinksTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");
        List<WebElement> activelinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href]"));
        System.out.println("Size of links and images: " + activelinks.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < activelinks.size(); j++) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            String response = connection.getResponseMessage();
            connection.disconnect();
            System.out.println(j + ". " + response + " " + activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
}

and it outputs
Size of links and images: 48
0. OK https://www.facebook.com/#
1. OK https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate/?privacy_mutation_token=eyJ0eXBlIjowLCJjcmVhdGlvbl90aW1lIjoxNzE0NTc2NjA1LCJjYWxsc2l0ZV9pZCI6MzgxMjI5MDc5NTc1OTQ2fQ%3D%3D&ars=facebook_login
2. OK https://www.facebook.com/#
3. OK https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/?ref_type=registration_form
...

